# Sum of data in varchar column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

i have to sum element in a column(SCENARIO1) that is varchar and contain data like (1,920, 270.00, 0, NULL) but when i try to convert data into int or decimal i get this error : 
"he command is wrong when converting value "4582014,00" to int type"

here is my request :

```
select sum( convert( int, SCENARIO1) )
from Mnt_Scenario_Exercice where code_pere='00000000'
```

any help please

Comment: you could convert to decimal and not int

Comment: yes i tried to do it, nut i get  the error yet, error when converting varchar to numeric !!

Comment: well, see my answer below then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
select sum(cast(replace(SCENARIO1, ',', '.') as decimal(29, 10)))
from Mnt_Scenario_Exercice
where code_pere = '00000000';
```

If you couldn't convert your `'4582014,00'` into decimal, there's a chance you have different decimal separator on your server. You could look what it is or just try `'.'`

Answer (score 2):

4582014,00 should be a decimal
try this (I assume that youre query is working) and changed convert(int into decimal)

> select sum(convert(decimal(20,2),replace(SCENARIO1, ',', '.'))) from Mnt_Scenario_Exercice where code_pere='00000000'

Comment: i try this, but ihave this error : "error when converting "270.00" to int type"

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the fact that the sum function isn't decoding SCENARIO1 as containing a CSV list of numbers.  The way the sum function is usually used is to sum a lot of numbers drawn from multiple rows, where each row provides one number.

Try doing it in two steps.  In step 1 convert the table into first normal form perhaps by UNPIVOTING.  The 1NF table will have one number per row, and will contain more rows than the initial table.

The second step is to compute the sum.  If you want more than one sum in the result, use GROUP BY to create groups, and then select a sum(somecolumn).  This will yield one sum for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I haven't got a way to test yet, but I will test and replace if incorrect.

```
SELECT sum(CAST (replace(SCENARIO1, ',', '') AS INT))
FROM   Mnt_Scenario_Exercice
WHERE  code_pere = '00000000';
```

EDIT: You can use a `numeric` for the cast if you need 4582014,00 to be 4582014.00

```
SELECT sum(CAST (replace(SCENARIO1, ',', '.') AS NUMERIC(10,2)))
    FROM   Mnt_Scenario_Exercice
    WHERE  code_pere = '00000000';
```

Comment: it's not throwing error but the result is not correct, for example i have this data : '4582014,00' '0' 'NULL' and the sum is 458201400 with your solution

Comment: @ucef, what should it be here? do you want 458201400 + 0 + null ?

Comment: you can't do it like that, or you'll turn 250.00 into 25000.

Comment: @RomanPekar, I was going by the example **'4582014,00'**, but if this should be a period, then I agree and I will change my answer.