# How can i sum an array like this in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this returned from two rows in my table, and I want to be able to display the sum in laravel blade.

`["212,703.00","212,703.00"]`

I have tried, but not working. the name of the column is `amount`

```
 $investamount = DB::table('investment')->get();
 return $investamount->sum('amount');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Eloquent Sum of relation's column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679678/laravel-eloquent-sum-of-relations-column)

Comment: no it does not answer my question

Answer (score 2):

You will need to use array_reduce for the special format you have

```php
$investamount = DB::table('investment')->pluck('amount')->toArray();
$investamount = array_reduce($investamount, function($carry, $item) {
    return $carry + str_replace(',','',$item);
});
```

Comment: Undefined variable: carry

Comment: compact(): Undefined variable: investamount

Comment: @PPK try it again, was a mistype. investAmount with a capital A

Comment: @PPK it was in the variable $sum, i've edited it. Here, naming is as you wanted..

Comment: Worked this is the answer

Comment: @PPK you should change the database field into a float instead of a string. but yeah,  carefull

Comment: it works great and give the exact result...are u still online?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using `varchar` for your `amount` field having comma then you can do it like this

```
DB::table('investment')->select("SUM(REPLACE(amount, ',', '')") as total)->get()
```

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SUM(amount)' in 'field list

Comment: @PPK you can use the sum method directly

Comment: You don't need to use get() when using the aggregate method as sum. Use

Comment: Yes i tried this before but it gave me 424 as the sum for 212,703.00","212,703.00"...what happens to the 703, 703??

Comment: are 703 stored on separate columns?

Comment: no same colume 212,703.00 times 2 is what i want..but its giving me 212 times 2 as result

Comment: @PPK 212,703.00 is a string format that is not a valid number. the sum just used what it could (212+212) and discarded the rest of the string.

Comment: How do i solve this problem? i need the answer of 212,703.00 + 212,703.00, but what i am getting is 424 as answer.

Comment: Use this `DB::table('investment')->select(SUM(REPLACE(amount, ',', '')) as total)->get()`

Comment: something is wrong with the code..not sure what it is

Comment: yes double quotes were missing. Try this  `DB::table('investment')->select("SUM(REPLACE(amount, ',', '')") as total)->get()` This will give you result in single line

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$investamount = DB::table('investment')->sum('amount');
```

or

```
$investamount = DB::table('investment')->pluck('amount')->toArray();
$sum = array_sum($investamount);
```

**EDITED**

```
$investamount = DB::table('investment')->select(DB::raw("SUM(amount) as sum"))->get();
return $investamount->sum;
```

Comment: i need the answer of 212,703.00 + 212,703.00, but what i am getting is 424 as answer.

Comment: i think you save amount as sting , so Answer has updated plz try

Comment: or try this -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18056550/sum-of-data-in-varchar-column

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you need

```php
return DB::table('investment')->get()->sum(function ($investment) {
    return (float) str_replace(',', '', $investment->amount);
});
```

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: wont work, the "," is the thousands separator not the decimal one. there is already a "." in the number

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using laravel [Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-sum). Then map the items to replace the commas.

**Example:**

```
return collect(DB::table('investment')->select('amount')->get())->map(function ($item) {
  return str_replace(',', '', $item->amount);
})->sum(); //This will return 425406‬.00
```

If you want to display the sum with commas in your blade template you can use `number_format()`

**Example:**

```
{{ number_format(sum, 2) }} //425,406‬.00
```